# Need to speed when using Automapper in an ASP.NET Core razor page

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC project using Razor pages. I'm using a repository and after that using Automapper to convert to a view model. The query in the repository is fast, but when I use Automapper to convert the data returned on a `listViewModel`, it is very slow when I get back more than 1000 rows.

This is a function to get all rows in the repository:

```
public IQueryable<ModelName> GetAllAsync()
{
    return context.ModelName
                  .OrderByDescending(m => m.CreateOn)
                  .Include(m => m.Customer)
                  .Include(m => m.Town);
}
```

And here is an example of how I use Automapper in the view:

```
var viewModelList = list.Select(m => _mapper.Map<ViewModel>(m))
                        .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: The query is fast, because you don't run the query, just prepare it. Then you iterate the query and each item will be get and mapped. Remove the .Select() clause and first get all items in a list and afterwards map the whole list to a list of your destination type. Then you see where your time is burn and I would bet it is not AutoMapper.

Comment: Also - if you're using `.ToListAsync()`, you should also use the `await` keyword: `var viewModelList = await list.Select(....).ToListAsync();`

Comment: @Oliver I'm fetching all items in a list I have more than 3000 items in the list and after that I mapped to viewmodel

Comment: @marc_s,  yeah I'm using  await but her I forgeted it

Comment: @Oliver Maybe I'm wrong in configuring automapper because I have more than one Include in query? 
I configuring  like this
CreateMap<ModelName,ViewModel>().ReverseMap();

Comment: @Oliver I think  the problem in convert  ToList() because now I'm trying map only with out ToList is work fine